# Style elements in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to add style on elements from json in a Vue js:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in json._items" class="help-inner-callout" v-html="item.text" style="top:item.top; left: item.left;"></div>
```

In my try loop is working and elements are filling with text by `v-html="item.text"` but style not applied. Can anyone have a look please, I just started learning Vue js..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to bind it (`v-bind:style` or `:style`) since you use `item`

```
:style="{top:item.top, left: item.left}"
```

Comment: Great, thanks! meanwhile, I was trying `v-bind:style="{ 'top': + item.top + ;'left': + item.left+}"` , but in a wrong way...